# Fail to connect PostgreSQL DB from my Linux User

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, terminal

I am new to technologies , please do not judge my question too strong :).

I installed in My Ubuntu 18.04 PostgreSQL 10.7. To be able to enter my DB I need to enter the following commands from my terminal. sudo -u postgres psql. 
Is there any shortened way where I can connect it from my Ubuntu User account. For example. if I input psql  it will open database environment where I can type PostgreSQL commands.

Thank you.

Comment: `psql -U postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute this command in your terminal :

```
alias psql='sudo -u postgres psql'
```

So the next time, you input psql and execute, you will be in database environment.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) [Create alias](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/) for this command `sudo -u postgres psql` .

2) Go to psql and create new superuser and database for it:

```
CREATE ROLE username SUPERUSER;
ALTER ROLE username WITH LOGIN;
CREATE DATABASE username;
```

Comment: To create or manage tables, no superuser role is needed. A regular user is the much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the superuser account for your normal database work. That is as if you were using `root` for everything in Linux.

You need to create a regular user with the privileges to create or modify tables in your database. This can be done by granting the user all privileges on the database (which is **not** the same as making that user a superuser) or make that user the owner of that database.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) `psql` tries to connect to a database with the name of the current Linux user and with a database user with the name of the current Linux user. So if you want to keep things simple create a user with your regular Linux user's name and an database that is owned by that user:

```
create user rob password 'somepassword';
create database rob owner = rob;
```

Assuming your Linux user is `rob`, then all you need to do is:

```
psql
```

and you are connected to a database where you can create and manage tables.

Depending on how you installed Postgres, you might need to adjust [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to allow `rob` to log in directly.

---

Again: please do **NOT** use the superuser account for your normal work.